# I don’t understant where that `value` come from, and what that `set` is

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

The task is:

> Modify the code of `makeCounter()` so that the counter can also decrease and set the number.

I don’t understant where that `value` come from, and what that `set` is.

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  function counter() {
    return count++
  }

  // Here is this `value`. I understand what it does. But what is it,
  // and where did it come from. How can I use it in general?
  counter.set = value => count = value;
  counter.decrease = () => count--;

  return counter;
}

let counter = makeCounter();

alert(counter()); // 0
alert(counter()); // 1

// Also here, what kind of `set` is this?
// I’ve seen one in `Map.prototype.set()`, but there is no `Map` here.
counter.set(10); // set the new count
alert(counter()); // 10
counter.decrease(); // decrease the count by 1
alert(counter()); // 10 (instead of 11)
```

[Source of the code](http://javascript.info/function-object).

Comment: `value` is a function parameter, `set` is a property.

Comment: Right... just a property. Just like decrease. Thanks for your time. I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and `value` is the name of the first parameter of that function.

```
counter.set = value => count = value;
counter.decrease = () => {
  count--;
  return counter;
}
```

The code above translates into this in ES5 syntax:

```
counter.set = function (value) {
  return count = value;
};
counter.decrease = function () {
  count--;
  return counter;
};
```

Comment: Oh! right. Sorry I got confused by the naming. It could be anything else...